# Is it common to analyze grammatically motivated vowel alternation as an occurence of discontinuous morphemes?

Tags: syntax, terminology, morphology

For example, are the triconsonantal roots in Arabic (like k-t-b --write) considered to be discontinuous morphemes?

How about the English roots (s-ng -- sing, sang, sung, song) and (beg-n -- begin, began, begun)?

Comment: The actual phenomena are the utterances that people use. How one organizes them is a decision based on utility and tradition, rather than on what is actually happening. Semitic languages started off being analyzed by triconsonantal roots, and that's been a tradition for millennia; but there's been so much borrowing that a case can be made for lexical items. As for English, generally a root system doesn't work well; only a few verbs have full vowel changes in principal parts. You want a root system, [try Lushootseed](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Lushootseed.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really a sociology and history of linguistics question (which is fine, I'm just saying it's a really hard one to answer). I do not think that most linguists or even more than 5% of linguists have a positive believe that Semitic roots and Germanic ablaut-related words constitute instances of the technical concept "discontinuous morpheme". One of the main reasons is that DM is not a technical concept, i.e. something that has a clear definition. The term derives from a 1945 paper in *Language* by Zellig Harris, and he in fact reduces ordinary grammatical agreement to the concept of "discontinuous morpheme", which is not what anybody in the modern world means by the term. His real point was to show that so-called discontinuous morphemes are simply a subtype of morphemes. Given Harris's general assumptions, Arabic *maktab, yaktubu, kitāb, katabat, kātib* have a common morpheme, and the elements of the morpheme are never continuous, which means that they are discontinous.

The term is used more often in Semitic linguistics than in the study of ablaut in English, so if you narrow the question to e.g. "discussion of root and pattern morphology by Semiticists", it might be frequent enough in that domain to be called "common",

Answer (score 3):

I do not know what you mean by "common", but one view is that Indo-European "ablaut" and Semitic "stem formation" are typologically very much the same thing. See for example Kuryłowicz, L’apophonie en sémitique. Kraków 1962.